# How to push down the entire page with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a top bar that is dynamically added to existing pages.

When it's loaded, it should push down the content of the entire page and then appear at the top.

The way it pushes down the content of the page is by adding the following CSS rule to the page:

```
body {padding-top: 50px}
```

The problem is that there are pages where this rule doesn't work properly. For example, pages with elements with absolute positioning.

Is there a better way to push the content of the page down?

Answer (score 2):

For `body` try setting `position` `relative` and then set `top` with some offset amount like `100px`. Of course change it to your needs.

Comment: Will this work for `absolute` positioned elements, can you create demo

Comment: Demo for this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/9t4fqy8a/ You'll have to *fight* with margins.

Comment: This doesn't push down fixed-positioned elements